# ActivtyNotFoundException but YES, it is declared in my AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: android, eclipse, android-manifest

in my application I call

```
startActivityForResult( new Intent(this, ShowPreferencesActivity.class), <some code>);
```

the activity is declared as :

```
package ca.qc.webalterpraxis.cinedroid.activity.preference;

public class ShowPreferencesActivity extends PreferenceActivity { ...}
```

and in my manifest I got :

```
<activty android:name=".activity.preference.ShowPreferencesActivity" android:label="@string/set_preferences">
```

But I receive an exception when I try to start the activity (in the first line of code of this question) :

```
E/AndroidRuntime(1830): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {ca.qc.webalterpraxis.cinedroid/ca.qc.webalterpraxis.cinedroid.activity.preference.ShowPreferencesActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

I tried everything I could :

- replacing, in the manifest, the name of the class with the fully qualified name of the class
- setting the intent class name using setClassName
- providing a default filter for the activity

I relaunched eclipse around 10 times, rebooted my computer, erased the application from the device, resintalled, etc...

I don't have any idea of what's happening. And the worse is that it was working before, but not anymore after I renamed the class. Something strange : even if I rename the class now, the AndroidManifest won't update in eclipse, I have to update it by hand..but it still works for other classes...

Also, please note that I have a test application, apart of the under test app, and the test app can't find the activity to instrument it, neither.

Oh, and last but not least, I am 100 % sure that the ShowPreferencesActivity is in the resulting dex file, I dexdumped it to check.

Thanks in advance for your time.
 (I use the maven-android-plugin)

Comment: I wouldn't work, my android package is ca.qc.webalterpraxis.cinedroid.

Comment: CTRL + CLICK ON ".activity.preference.ShowPreferencesActivity"

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion, without the I (see answer below) it doesn't work... But when activity is spelled right, it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all, I found my problem : the tag in the manifest was

```
<activty
```

and not

```
<activity
```

But why does eclipse allow that ???!!!

Comment: as there is no dtd given, it does not know where to check for validation, it only complains about the `android` attributes...

Comment: why isn't there no dtd ? The structure of an AndroidManifest.xml file is fully documented in android resources on the android developper web site.

Comment: Yes, but there is no reference to a dtd in the root tag, so the editor/eclipse has no idea where to look at for validation. It can't use google alone :)

Comment: lol, and could we provide a dtd attribute at the root tag of AndroidManifest.xml ?

Comment: nope, is there any ?.. There ain't any : http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_frm/thread/d85b6c2d0e301126/8dbbcb11543672e5?lnk=gst&q=schema%2Bexist#8dbbcb11543672e5